# is the string type a header file or in the standard namespace?

Tags: c++, variables, types, namespaces, header-files

I'm a newbie to C++, and programming for the most part, just started learning a few days ago, and I'm a bit confused about this.
Is the string variable type in the standard namespace?
I found I can use strings without using `#include <string>`. I can also use `using namespace std;`, to activate the use of strings, or `std::string mystring;` for example.

I know that using `using namespace std;` allows for the use of all commands/functions within the standard namespace, ie `cout`.

If string is within the standard namespace, is `#include <string>` the same as saying `using std::string;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` is a class defined in the standard library header `<string>`. Like all names of the standard library, it is declared in the namespace `std`.

> is `#include <string>` the same as saying `using std::string;` ?

No. Those have two entirely different meanings.

`#include <string>` means "include the content of the header `<string>` into this file". The header contains the definition of the class `std::string` among other things.

`using std::string;` essentially means "declare the identifier `string` as a type alias to `std::string` in the current namespace".

Comment: So if we laid it out as a sort of hierarchy, if would be something like this more or less?

Namespace
    Header
       Class

calling std would call everything "under" the namespace, whereas calling <string> would call just the content within that header?

Answer (score 0):

"I found I can use strings without using `#include <string>`"

That's coincidence. You included another header that by chance included `<string>`. This is allowed in C++, and pretty common for e.g. `<sstream>`. But you can't rely on this. If you need `std::string`, you should `#include <string>`.

This will include `std::string`, from the `std` namespace. This namespace is actually defined by multiple headers. Unlike classes, namespaces do not need to be defined in one header; they can be spread over multiple.